# Bundler not working: in `[]': undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm having some troubles with my Rails app after installing (and removing) Compass. `bundle install` gives me the following:

```
/Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler 1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:10:in `[]': undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:32:in `without'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:26:in `without='
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:105:in `install'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:33:in `run'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `block in invoke'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `call'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `invoke'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:159:in `block in start'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:378:in `start'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:138:in `start'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/gems/bundler-1.0.0.beta.2/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /Users/[..]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3beta/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I've tried cleaning out the gemset and re-installing Bundler and other gems without luck. I've also tried creating a new app - bundler works fine here, so I guess the problem is somewhere withint my app code, but I have no idea where to look.

Any ideas? :-) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first look in the Gemfile for, then check for .bundle/ and vendor/cache/, remove them and launch this:

```
bundle package
```

this should resolve.

Answer (score 11):

For others with this issue, I needed to delete an empty `~/.bundler/config` file I was messing with.